# How to set the origin width and height for image in `background: url()`?

Tags: html, css

So I try to use the image like background. But for now I face the problem with dimensions of it. When I try to set the `width and height by 100%` I got an empty container without image.

Question - how to set image size by it's `original width and height` in case we do not know the `size` of the `image` before upload?

```
background: url(https://img.com/1000061770.jpg) no-repeat;
background-size: contain;
height: 100%; // not work
width: 100%; // not work
```

Comment: use it as image ... with background-image you cannot

Comment: The image is not loading, maybe your url is wrong

Comment: image link is not real for some reasons

Answer (score 1):

When you set the background of an empty element it wont be seen unless the element has a width and a height

For your question, i would assume you're managing the upload of the images, so from there you can figure out the dimensions of it.

If not

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() { alert("Width : "+img.width+ " Height : "+img.height); }
img.src = "YOUR IMG URL";
```

other than that if you're just going to display the image use the img tag